# Exercise about adjunction of preorders

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, adjoint-functors

I must prove that a functor $G:Y\to X$ that preserves limits has a left adjoint $F$, where $X$ and $Y$ are preorder categories with all limits (i.e. all products). I don't see how to define $F$ with this data; I thought of sending every $x\in X$ to the initial or terminal object of $Y$ but it doesn't work, and I can't see an other choice. Can anyone give me an hint?

Comment: You could apply the adjoint functor theorem here, as a last resort. But you should start by meditating on "$F x \le y$ if and only if $x \le G y$". How might you exploit this to get a formula for $F x$? Obviously you will have to do something to eliminate the variable $y$.

Comment: Adjoint functor theorem aside, which we didn't study, your suggestion is exactly what I was thinking to do. And still, I can't figure out how to define this $F$

Comment: Well, you might form the set $\{ y : x \le G y \}$. Now what?